# How to add transparent hover overlay to these carousel portfolio images

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

https://jsfiddle.net/dmaltron87/odpeLLv6/

Trying to make it so a simple overlay with text appears when I hover over the images, but I can't get anything to work with this code. I found this in a demo tutorial and edited for my site, but my javascript understanding/skills are still pretty basic. I'm not too picky about the end result, just want ideas.

tried something like this, and added a css overlay with opacity=0 then hover at .75. straightforward, but didn't work.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src=".." alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture the [`mouseenter()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events and add some dynamic content.

Here's an example:

```js
$(".carousel img").on("mouseenter", function() {
  //start hover
  let me = $(this);
  let position = me.position();

  //create overlay
  let overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>');

  //set position and size
  overlay.css({
    left: position.left,
    top: position.top,
    height: me.height(),
    width: me.width()
  });

  //append overlay
  me.after(overlay);
});

//remove hover when the overlay is de-hovered
$(".carousel").on("mouseleave", ".overlay", function() {
  //end hover
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/00AA00?text=Overlay) no-repeat center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2/" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3/" />
</div>
```